# Access XSD tags from XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

Some languages (notably, DFDL, and another I am considering building) use foreign attributes (i.e. attributes in a namespace other than `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`) on XSD schema tags in order to describe additional metadata about the items declared in it (e.g. complexType, simpleType, element). Example follows:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     xmlns:dfdl="http://www.ogf.org/dfdl/dfdl-1.0/">
    <xs:element name="input">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence dfdl:separator=":" dfdl:separatorPosition="infix">
                <xs:element name="label" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

(`dfdl` is the foreign attribute prefix)

It would be very helpful to be able to access this metadata in a schema-aware XSLT, such as for writing conversion routines. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I only remember that the MSXML SOM (schema object model) has an `unhandledAttributes` property on a schema item to access the attributes that are not defined in the schema namespace (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762294(v=vs.85)). I am not sure whether Saxon or Java has something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple solution in Saxon. The compiled schema (whether in the form of Java objects or SCM files) doesn't retain anything from the source schema document that isn't needed for the purpose of validation.

However there might be a difficult and long-winded solution.

Take a look at the saxon:type() and saxon:schema() extension functions. Applying saxon:type() to a validated element node will get you a map-like representation of the complex type object, and the `implementation` property of this map gets you to a Java `UserComplexType` object. The `getParticle()` method on this object (which you can call from XPath as a Java reflexive extension function) returns a `Particle` object representing the `xs:sequence` element. `Particle` implements `Location` which gives you via `getSystemId()` and `getLineNumber()` the source location of the particle in the original XSD. Retrieve the XSD module using `doc()`, and search for a particle with the correct line number, then retrieve its attributes.

Comment: Would it be worthwhile to write up a use-case for XSLT 4.0? I see very few changes to schema handling in 4.0

Comment: By all means contribute an issue on the QT4CG GitHub. I think the requirement is sufficiently complex and specialised, though, that it won't make the cut. Before looking at non-XSD defined attributes we'd have to catch up with saxon:schema by defining an XPath API to the XSD schema component model, and that's a pretty big undertaking.